# loss is "nan" and accuracy is 0 in a CNN (Keras) model in EEG classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to classify an EEG dataset I found online. (BCI comp III, Dataset V)

I am just playing around with different models as a side project, and I though I'd start with a CNN.

This is the piece of code for extracting the data from the files:

```
def ext_data(subNum, rawNum):
file_name = r'C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\EEG\EEG datasets\BCI COMP III\Dataset V\train_subject{}_raw{:02d}.asc'.format(subNum, rawNum)
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt(file_name)
print("count of original data is {}".format(len(data)))
org_data = []
i = 0
while True:
    if i == len(data)-1:
        break
    meta = []
    cl = data[i,32]
    meta.append(data[i,0:32])
    while 1:
        i += 1
        if i == len(data)-1:
            meta.append(data[i, 0:32])
            org_data.append([np.array(meta).reshape(len(meta),32),cl])
            break
        if data[i,32] == cl:
            meta.append(data[i,0:32])
        else:
            org_data.append([np.array(meta).reshape(len(meta),32),cl])
            break
    #print(i)
print(len(org_data))
return np.array(org_data)
```

and then I make the training labels and data this way:

```
    # total number of inptu samples = 104
data = np.ones(shape=[104, 2], dtype=object)
index = 0
for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in range(1, 4):
        print("index is {}".format(index))
        dum = ext_data(i, j)
        data[index:len(dum) + index] = dum
        index += len(dum)
train_x = np.zeros(shape = [104,8000,32], dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(104):
    for j in range(32):
        train_x[i,:,j] = beta_filter(data[i,0][0:8000,j])
train_x = train_x/40
train_y = np.array(data[:,1])
```

**beta_filter** is just a band-pass filter and a notch filter:

```
def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=3):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    sos = butter(order, [low, high], analog=False, btype='band', output='sos')
    return sos

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=3):
        sos = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
        y = sosfiltfilt(sos, data)
        return y

def butter_notch_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order = 3):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    sos = butter(order, [low, high], analog=False, btype='stop', output='sos')
    y = sosfiltfilt(sos, data)
    return y

def beta_filter(input):
    beta = butter_bandpass_filter(input, 12, 30, 512)
    beta = butter_notch_filter(beta,48,52,512)
    return beta
```

and finally, this is the model I made:

```
def generate_model():
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    
    # first convolutional layer
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2),
    
    # second convolutional layer
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2),

    # fully connected classifier
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')  # 3 outputs
])
return model
```

and finally, compile the model like this:

```
model = generate_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
            metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=15, batch_size=1)
```

but when training starts, I got **nan** for loss and 0 for accuracy! sometimes accuracy starts with a value of 0.0903,  and then goes to 0 and stays there.

I generated matrices of random values (`np.random.rand(size)`) to check the model, and ofc got an accuracy of 0.33 (the chance accuracy, three classes).

I also checked for `nan` within the input, and got nothing.

what would be the problem? is it the model? or is the data fundamentally wrong?

What would be the problem?

**P.S**: I only use up to 8000 data points for the input to avoid the variable length input, as inputs have different lengths.

**P.S**: this is what the filter does to the data:

Unfiltered data:

[image]

filtered data:

[image]

This is one random input vector from the 32 columns of the input matrix.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
```

to

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
```

You use `from_logits=True` when the last layer of your `model` doesn't have an activation like `softmax` or `sigmoid` (without that activation it will return logits and hence you can have it set to `True` else `False`).

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I did it, but still getting the same thing

Comment: @NeuroEng Now that I see your batch size is only 1. Increase the batch size to anything that fits in your ram from `8`,`16`,`32`... and so on.

Comment: I changed to 8 and 32, and still got the same results. if the model gives the chance accuracy on random data, would not that imply that the model is working fine and the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: Okay. Now I have a couple of questions. Where is your model's input layer and what is the input shape? Also, How many classes do you have, and are they mutually exclusive?

Comment: The input data are 104 input sets each having a dimension of 32x8000 (the longer legnth was variable, but I only chose up to 8000, max was 10100), the data has 3 classes

Comment: By "where is your input layer" I mean there is literally no "InputLayer" in your model in which you define the input shape.

Comment: i defined it as `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(32,8000,1))` but it does not make a difference

Comment: @NeuroEng where does that 32 come from?

Comment: The data consists of 32 channels of  data, each being 8000 long

Comment: @NeuroEng then is your input shape for a sample (8000,1). I though its a image.